# Manipulating Windows file permissions in Java

Tags: java, windows

Using Java how could I manipulate the access permissions of a file in Windows?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Java 6, File class gives you setExecutable, setWritable, etc. See: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

On older Java versions this is not possible; you have to exec OS commands to do that:

Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -r myFile");
```

Unix:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 myFile");
```

Comment: chmod won't work in windows, attrib -R or +R will change the read-only flag

Comment: You may want to be a bit more restrictive with the Unix permissioning, btw. 777 gives everyone everything :-)

Comment: Obviously, 777 was an example. If another question is asked on how to use chmod or attrib, I'm more than happy to answer ;)

Comment: @Rich: Instead of `attrib` on Windows you probably want to use `cacls`. `cacls /?` in a command prompt for more information.

Answer (score 10):

The new Java 7 [java.nio.file.attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/package-summary.html) package makes all of this a lot easier. It provides views onto the complete set of file attributes, including [Posix file permissions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermissions.html).

Comment: On Windows 7 attempting to get Posix attributes throws UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: How do we go about solving the problem in windows without having to run a command? Is there a common library that we can use to set permissions on all operating systems?

Comment: This answer is a little bit short, but the java.nio.file.attribute package includes also ACL handling for Windows!