# Why Java file permission methods return true on windows

Tags: java, windows, file-permissions

I have been asked with this question, since I'm not a Windows user I could not answer it.

Would you please explain me why the following piece of code does not return correct results when is executed on **Windows**, while it returns precise results when is run on **Linux**.

But eventually on windows it raise an **exception** since OS does not let the program to create the folder.

***we use JDK 6***

We remove all **permissions** from a folder `c:\temp`

[image]

and we check the permissions in the program and all methods return true!!!

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's because you're working with Access Control Lists (ACL) instead of POSIX files permissions... Don't know, just guessing.

Comment: Is it true that we should use `checkAccess` method to get the permission details of a file (ACL) ?

Comment: is this article explaining the same problem? http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4420020

Comment: I guess this bug report is talking about that ("The problem is that access *ONLY* checks the file or directory's
permissions.  It knows nothing about system security."). Here's what I found at another Stackoverflow question: Java 7 NIO has a brand new way to query file attributes - permissions included -(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/package-frame.html). (SO Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198517/manipulating-windows-file-permissions-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, I'm already aware of the NIO in JDK 7, but looking for a workaround for JDK 6.