# Java: copying files with double extentions

Tags: java

Hello I took on to a little side project today

It's a program that copies files from one folder to another to simplify playing a hotSeat game via dropbox

Now I need to copy a file called Medieval2.preference.cfg

```
public void setMultiplayer() throws Exception{
    Path origin = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Dropbox", "MTWMultiplayer","propertyFiles","multi.cfg");
    Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Medieval II Total War\\medieval2.preference.cfg");

    Files.copy(origin, destination, REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

public void setSingleplayer() throws Exception{
    Path origin = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Dropbox", "MTWMultiplayer","propertyFiles","single.cfg");
    Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Medieval II Total War\\medieval2.preference.cfg");

    Files.copy(origin, destination, REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

this code doesn't work and I've got a feeling it's because of the double extension in medieval2.preference.cfg

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error you're getting?

Comment: Ok after having a better look at my stacktrace I figure the error occurs because the file is read only

is there a way to edit the settings in order to make the file not read only,  copy it and then make it read only-again?

Comment: Read only wouldn't affect the source file, only the destination.  I'm almost completely certain you're running into a Windows security issue (program files are a protected area).  Check out this link: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/179931-writing-program-files-folder-how-access-denied.html  TL;DR: Run your program as an administrator (if using command line, run command line as admin then run your program).

Comment: hmmm I doubt this is the problem because I have working code that copy's other files from and to the same folder. also the code works when I leave out 1 of the extensions.

Comment: Interesting! I suppose it's possible that copying in that way tries to open the file in write mode rather than read - can you edit the file permissions (I think by right clicking and going to 'Properties', but I haven't used Windows in a while so I might be wrong) to allow writing, and see what that does?

Comment: Same error

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Medieval II Total War\medieval2.preference.cfg
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:165)
....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90555/discussion-between-soong-and-fox125).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into a file permissions error - the output file already exists and it's read only.  You can change the file permissions programmatically in Java via the instructions found at [Manipulating Windows file permissions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198517/manipulating-windows-file-permissions-in-java).  This will let you modify the file.